# How to ignore case and space in laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I have a table named `company_profile`

[image]

I want to search name ignoring case and space. Let me explain here id #1 has value of `name`: `Bracnet Academy` when I try to add another entry with `bracnetacademy` then it will update id #1 instead of inserting new one.

I tried as follows:

```
function onSetupCorporateName(){
     $data = post();
     if(empty($data['name'])) 
        throw new ApplicationException("Please enter your company name first.");

    $data['name'] = strtolower($data['name']);

    $searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $data['name'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 
     
    $companyProfile = CompanyProfile::where(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {                      
                          foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
                            $q->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
                          }
                    });
     
     $user = MyUser::find(Auth::getUser()->id);
     if($companyProfile->count()){
        $user->company_profile_id = $companyProfile->first()->id; 
     }
     else{
        $companyProfile = new CompanyProfile;
        $companyProfile->name = $data['name'];
        $companyProfile->save();
        $user->company_profile_id = $companyProfile->id;
     }

     $user->update();
     return Redirect::to('dashboard/company/info/'.$companyProfile->id);
}
```

It works for the following case:

1. Existing name is: `bracnetacademy`
2. New Entry name is: `bracnet academy`

But I want to make it work for any cases. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly you want, `add` or `update` ?

Comment: if found then update otherwise add

Comment: Then you can do one thing: First convert existing values into lowercase and remove space. do same with new values and then compare and check that it exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its using `regexp` to query and the `' *'` allows for any number of spaces between characters, so if we put `' *'` between every character, and remove all spaces from our search string it should ignore spaces

```
CompanyProfile::whereRaw('lower(company_profile.name) regexp (?)',[strtolower(implode(' *',str_split(str_replace(' ','',$data[name]))))])->get();
```

Although if $data[name] contains special regex characters like `*()^+` this will cause problems so you might want to escape them